What is the distinction between neutralizing and screening a charge?
I posted a question earlier about the electrical chage of electrons being neutralized inside an atom by their proxity to the opposite charge nucleous.  One comment implied that I used incorrect termology and that the charge was merely screened and not neutralized?  Is this true?  If so what is the technical distinction between the two?

I am not sure there is a large difference. I have heard the term screening used to describe how an outer electron can see a lower effective charge because of screening from an inner electron. If you used neutralized to express the same concept, I wouldn't worry about it.

Neutralizing a charged object often means adding an equivalent charge of the opposite sign such that the monopole charge moment vanishes.
Screening is not the same thing. Usually, a total or even partial screening is obtained when a distribution of charge of the opposite sign moves close to a given charge, thus reducing the total electric field generated by the original charge beyond the screening charge.
A neutralized body behaves as a zero-charge object (it can still have electric multipole moments). A screened object remains a charged object, although its electric field is weakened beyond the screening charges.
In the Statistical Mechanics of charged systems, it is usual to distinguish between global neutrality, i.e., when the system is made by the same amount of positive and negative charge, and local neutrality, corresponding to the case when a distribution of oppositely charged particles screens each charge.
Two significant examples of the use of the two terms are the following:

the capture of an electron neutralizes a positive $Na^+$ ion;
in an atom, the electrons totally screen the nuclear charge at a large distance.

It is clear that the two concepts are interrelated, although they put a different emphasis on the underlying phenomena.

Would it be fair to say that electrons with an atomic structure would have less electric repulsion with each other than free electrons?  If so would you explain this by neutralization or screening?

@DerekSeabrooke No, the screening of atomic electrons affects only the nucleus-electron interaction. It doesn't play a role in the electron-electron interaction.

What makes you think that?

@DerekSeabrooke If you study one of the simplest examples of screening, the Debye screening of a charged impurity in electrolytic solutions, you realize that the added charge does not affect the effective ion-ion interaction. Unfortunately, a summary of Debye's theory does not fit in the space of a comment or an answer on PSE.

I looked into but I am still confused how one could claim the prescence of a nucleous can have no effect on the behavior of electrons towards one another.  For instance electrons are densely packed within an atom and free electrons would probably not come so close to each other.  How is this consistent with Debye?

@DerekSeabrooke, I suspect you are trying to reverse the usual way of thinking in Physics. One can explore the consequences of a physical situation, for example, the presence of bound electrons around a nucleus. If the mathematical description of the system allows us to reinterpret it as a set of screened electrons, that is fine. But we cannot pretend that Nature behaves as we like. If there is no level of description of the system equivalent to a screened electron-electron interaction, that's it. To the best of my knowledge of the subject, nobody could find such an effect.
